# Performance of nodejs-opencv

Tags: node.js, opencv

I have got a use case in which I have to do image search in node JS application. I have image hash stored in database, so I need to calculate hash in nodeJS application. I may have more computer vision use cases in future.
 I came across  `nodejs-opencv` module, but none of the blogs talk about its performance. As nodeJS is not supposed to be used for CPU intensive tasks and computer vision algorithms may need heavy processing I am not sure how well it will scale. 
 Has someone used it in production and provide some details ?

Answer (score 0):

Which nodejs OpenCV library are you talking about? If you pick one that provides javascript bindings from a native node module then you will have the same performance as with C++. I am currently working on an OpenCV 3.x native node addon to use OpenCV with javascript and can tell you that there is really no difference in performance. However there are also implementations in pure javascript without the need of setting up the OpenCV c++ library on your server or local system but most of the CV tasks will be significantly slower if implemented in javascript as you already guessed.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way to use computer vision in NodeJS project is move the calculations into C++ codespace ([native addon](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/node-gyp-opencv)) and apply [Workers](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) for multithreading